# How to disable Quartz Scheduler on jboss6

Tags: jboss, quartz-scheduler, jboss6.x

Does the jboss6 appserver runtime have a dependency on Quartz Scheduler?
Can I remove this if I don't have a dependency on scheduling any jobs?
What files should I remove to disable this dependency? (Should I just remove quartz-ra.rar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jboss is not that modular as many may think :) Quartz is used to implement EJB timers, if you remove it, you will lost that functionality. 
In overall, just remove quartz-ra.rar and then start server, is if starts then good, if not, try to fix it. There is no easy way.